# How can I access nuxt.config.js settings from JavaScript?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a statically generated site (npx nuxt generate) using Nuxt 2. I use dynamic routing and have listed the routes in generate.routes inside nuxt.config.js. So far so good. In order to restrict the site to *only* serve up the dynamic routes I want, I have to implement a validate() function on the page to make sure that the path is correct. For example:

```js
// nuxt.config.js:
generate: {
    routes: [
      "/calculatrice/indice-de-masse/",
      "/calculator/body-fat/",
    ]
}
```

```js
// pages/_tool/_targetlanguage/index.vue: 

// note dynamic routing
async validate({ params, store }) {
   /* validate dynamic routes. Todo: further validate subdirectory */
   if (["calculator", "calculatrice"].includes(params.tool)) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
},
```

What I would really like to have is a way to avoid this duplication and pull the generated routes out of nuxt.config.js but I can't find a way to access those config values from within my Vue page.

Alternatively, I could live with a third file which contains all the supported mappings which is then used by both nuxt.config.js and my page.

Comment: Not sure if it applies, but take a look at defining them in `publicRuntimeConfig` in your `nuxt.config.js` file then you can access them with `this.$config.my_routes`
take a look at https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#publicruntimeconfig and https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#using-your-config-values

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was quite simple. Create an external JavaScript file:

**dynamicRoutes.js**

```
var cfg = {
  dynamicRoutes: [ "/calculatrice/indice-de-masse/", "/calculator/body-fat/"]
  ]
}
module.exports = cfg;
```

**Update nuxt.config.js**

```
const cfg = require("./dynamicRoutes.js");

generate: {
  routes: cfg.dynamicRoutes,
},
```

**Update validate function inside Vue page**

```
const cfg = require("/dynamicRoutes.js");

async validate({ params }) {
  const path = "/" + params.tool + "/" + params.target_language + "/";
  return !!cfg.dynamicRoutes.includes(path);
},
```

Works for me! Hope this helps someone else.

Note, could probably combine this with @Jimmar solution to avoid the extra imports in pages.